# How to include fragment (#) in the URL computed by redirect?

Tags: 8, redirection

I want to redirect the user to an internal path that includes a fragment (the part of the url that is introduced with a #), e.g.:

```
/comment/19#comment-19
```

I know how to build the path without the fragment portion. If `$cid` is the comment id, this will do it:

```
$this->redirect($comment->permalink()->getRouteName(), array('comment' => $cid));
```

But how can I add a fragment to the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment is stored in the options of the url, also the cid in the parameters. So you'll find all information you need in the url `permalink()` returns:

```
  $url = $comment->permalink();

  $this->redirect($url->getRouteName(), $url->getRouteParameters(), $url->getOptions());
```